# Core Data: should I write one data access object/manager/controller per entity?

Tags: ios, core-data, orm, dao

My core data model is reasonably simple but hierarchical.  A Person entity has a set of Fund entities. Each Fund a set of Stock entities. Each stock has a set of Price entities.  So:

```
Person: to many Funds
Fund: to many Stocks
Stock: to many Prices
```

Architecturally, should I have a class that manages the CRUD operations for each Core Data Entity?  I call this a DAO (data access object) and manager interchangeably.
Further, if I have a manager class for each entity, what would I write in the manager if I want to grab a Person entity?

In order to get a Person, wouldn't I need to get a Person's funds; then use the Fund DAO/manager to get a Fund's stocks; then use the Stock's DAO/manager to get a stock's Prices?

This seems to be necessary to me in order to construct a "complete" Person. But what if I only want to grab a Person's last name?  That's just a field in a Person and doesn't require any relationships.  Should a getter get the entire object graph for a given Person?  And If I set a Person, do I need to set all of his/her related objects as well?

Thanks!

Comment: How you managed CRUD operations depends somewhat on your UI.  A Fund is presumably are independent of a Person, in other words, a Fund could have more than one person associated with it (or not if the person is the Fund Manager).  Similarly Stocks are independent of Funds.  A Stock can exist even if there is no Fund it belongs to.  So if you want to be able to independently create Stocks and Funds and People and later associated them then independent UI controllers for doing so may be necessary. I would usually favour this approach because if gives you more flexibility.

Comment: However without understanding more about your specific application its hard to make any suggestions.  Technically you don't need to set any attributes to create an object in Core Data, assuming you don't have any mandatory fields or relationships.  However your business rules may call for something more than just an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> But what if I only want to grab a Person's last name? That's just a field in a Person and doesn't require any relationships. Should a getter get the entire object graph for a given Person?

When you get a `Person`, his `fund`s will be fault. [Faulting and Uniquing - Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

2.

> And If I set a Person, do I need to set all of his/her related objects as well?

No, you don't need set all of his related objects as well unless the related objects is not optional. So when your person need to have a fund, you can just add the fund to the person.

---

In my development habit, I would like to category the person, and add some class method like:

`+ [Person newPersonWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName];`

to deal with the `Person` related things.